# How to change font color of numbers in TextEdit

Tags: macos, fonts, colors, textedit

I was wondering if changing the color of the font for certain numbers in TextEdit was possible.

For exemple to have all '1's in blue, '2's red etc...

If that's impossible in TextEdit, can someone suggest a similar software able to do so and read .txt files ?

Comment: what is wrong with changing the _attributes_ of the text?

Comment: @holex I am looking for a way to have numbers appear directly with a specific color font. Can you develop what you mean by changing the attributes ?

Comment: I can develop it but you could do that too by setting up the [tying-attributes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextview/1449487-typingattributes) for e.g. changing the colour of all numbers inside the [`textViewDidChangeSelection(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstextviewdelegate/1449363-textviewdidchangeselection) delegate method.

Comment: What do you plan to use this for exactly please? I have some ideas how to do it, but whether they will work for depends on what you are trying to achieve. The fact that you mention coloured numbers in a text file worries me too...

Comment: @MarkSetchell It's to more efficiently distinguish a group of '1's in between a long list of '0's, for exemple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fun! **macOS** includes **Perl** and `textutil` which is used for changing document formats, so you can do something like what you want without needing to install anything...

```
#!/bin/bash
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $/=\1; }
          s/0/<font color="red"    >0<font color="black">/ || 
          s/1/<font color="green"  >1<font color="black">/ ||
          s/2/<font color="blue"   >2<font color="black">/ ||
          s/3/<font color="cyan"   >3<font color="black">/ ||
          s/4/<font color="magenta">4<font color="black">/ ||
          s/5/<font color="yellow" >5<font color="black">/ ||
          s/6/<font color="pink"   >6<font color="black">/ ||
          s/7/<font color="orange" >7<font color="black">/ ||
          s/8/<font color="teal"   >8<font color="black">/ ||
          s/9/<font color="gray"   >9<font color="black">/ ||
          s/\n/<br>/;
         ' "$1"  | textutil -format html -convert rtf -stdin -stdout > output.rtf
```

Save that as `go` and make it executable, just once with:

```
chmod +x go
```

Then you can convert any document like this:

```
./go input.txt
```

and it will make `output.rtf`.

So, if I start with the following in `input.txt`:

```
1234567890 I love RTF and HTML but not 2 much and I can't spell, or count 1,000,222
1 man had 2 dogs and 333 cats
```

I end up with:

[image]

---

The **Perl** reads 1 character at a time, because of `$/=\1;`. It then replaces any digit with an HTML `font` tag with a different colour, then sets the colour back to black after the digit. The output is then passed to `textutil` which is told to treat the input as `html` and make the output RTF.

---

I have spent all day on this and I still have no idea why one of your documents works and the other doesn't. The only thing I can say is that `textutil` seems not to crash when I comment out the following line that changes the colours of the `1`s in your document to green! I have no idea why!

```
s/1/<font color="green"  >1<font color="black">/ ||
```

I re-wrote it in a different way even, but it is still the same. I will put the code below so that others can play with it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

   my ($i, $x, %HofH);

   # Initialise table mapping input bytes to output/actions
   # So it's a hash of hashes, each hash stores the corresponding output string and whether it set colour
   foreach $i ('A'..'Z', 'a'..'z' ){
      $x = ord($i);
      $HofH{$x}{out}    = $i;
   }
   # Set up the coloured digits 0-9
   $i=48; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='red'>0")    ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   #$i=49; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("1")                      ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;    # THIS CRASHES TEXTUTIL ???
   $i=50; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='blue'>2")   ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   $i=51; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='cyan'>3")   ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   $i=52; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='magenta'>4"); $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   $i=53; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='yellow'>5") ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   $i=54; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='pink'>6")   ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   $i=55; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='orange'>7") ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   $i=56; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='teal'>8")   ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;
   $i=57; $HofH{$i}{out} = sprintf("<font color='grey'>9")   ; $HofH{$i}{colour}=1;

   # Special cases - CR, LF, ampersand
   $i=9;  $HofH{$i}{out} = " ";
   $i=10; $HofH{$i}{out} = "<br>\n";
   $i=13; $HofH{$i}{out} = "<br>\n";
   $i=39; $HofH{$i}{out} = "&amp;";
   $i=47; $HofH{$i}{out} = "/";
   $i=61; $HofH{$i}{out} = "=";
   $i=63; $HofH{$i}{out} = "?";
   $i=40; $HofH{$i}{out} = "(";
   $i=41; $HofH{$i}{out} = ")";
   $i=45; $HofH{$i}{out} = "-";
   $i=58; $HofH{$i}{out} = ":";
   $i=59; $HofH{$i}{out} = ";";
   $i=46; $HofH{$i}{out} = ".";
   $i=44; $HofH{$i}{out} = ",";
   $i=32; $HofH{$i}{out} = " ";
   $i=60; $HofH{$i}{out} = "&lt;";
   $i=62; $HofH{$i}{out} = "&gt;";

   open(my $FILE, $ARGV[0]) or die $!;
   binmode($FILE);

   local $/ = \1;
   my $cnt=0;
   while ( my $byte = <$FILE> ) {
      my $x = ord($byte);
      if(defined $HofH{$x}){
         printf("%s",$HofH{$x}{out});
         printf("<font color='black'>") if defined $HofH{$x}{colour}
      } else {
         printf STDERR "ERROR: Character number %d ignored at byte offset %d\n",$x,$cnt;
      }
      $cnt++;
   }

   close $FILE;
```

You run it with:

```
thisScript.pl someFile.txt | textutil -format html -convert rtf -stdin -stdout > output.rtf
```

Comment: Nice this is exactly what I'm looking for. Although I get `"Can't open : No such file or directory."` when I enter `' "$1"  | textutil -format html -convert rtf -stdin -stdout > output.rtf`

Comment: Why are you entering that? You need to save **all 14 lines** of the code into a file like I said. The single quote in your comment closes the opening quote on line 2. The script says `perl -pe 'BEGIN... ' "$1" | textutil ...`

Comment: What kind of file is `go` before `chmod +x go` ?

Comment: `chmod +x` changes the mode of the file by adding the executable bit - the contents remain unchanged. Are you typing the code into `TextEdit`? If so, you need to go on the **Format** menu and click **Make Plain Text** else it will be RTF format rather than text.

Comment: At first I wrote the code in TextEdit and saved it as a txt file (yes by clicking Make Plain Text). But then the command `chmod +x go` would not find the file, unless I'd write `chmod +x go.txt`. But the command `/.go input.txt` still returns `-bash: /.go: No such file or directory`. I think the txt file is not being converted to an exec.

Comment: Your file is called `go.txt`, so you cannot run `./go` - you need to exit **TextEdit**, start a Terminal and run `mv go.txt go` which will rename `go.txt` as plain `go`. Then you can carry on.

Comment: Ah, finally made it work. It's because it's not `/.go input.txt` but `./go input.txt`. A new problem : output.rtf can't be read, tried TextEdit, Preview, Word, Pages

Comment: It has to do with my input file. I tried with an exemple like you did and it worked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182850/discussion-between-nawra-c-and-mark-setchell).

Comment: I have spent all day on this and have no idea why your second document doesn't work. There are no weird characters in it. If I give it 458 lines it works fine, but if I give it 459 lines it crashes `textutil`. If I put lines 400-500 in a new document it works so there seems to be nothing in the document that `textutil can't process. If I give it 1,000 lines of a different file it works fine, so there seems to be no limit on the number of lines. I am confused! Sorry!

Comment: This isn't actually an answer to the original question. This tells how to change the font in an RTF file. TextEdit merely displays the result. 

However, Nawara C says this is exactly what they were looking for, so it's the right answer to the wrong question. They do ask if not with TextEdit, then with what. The answer shows how to do it with the shell and perl. 

To answer the original question and make this change from within TextEdit would require executing the script on the current file and then reloading the resulting file. That's a couple of steps beyond where this this answer stops.

Comment: @AugustMohr I can see where you are coming from and largely agree. It was the best I could do at the time and nobody seems to have come up with anything better, or even just an alternative, in the intervening 2.5 years though. I shall stay tuned...